# undefined behaviour of macro in for loop

Tags: c

can anyone explain me the output
I have code like

```
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
             int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};
             for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++)
             {
              printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
              }
```

It shows no output why it is so ?  
But when i change the value of d in for loop like d=1 it shows the output why?  
if i remove macro TOTAL_ELEMENT wit d<=4 ; i get the desired output why ?

Comment: Hint: how many times the body of the `for` will be executed? And what's the "value" of `TOTAL_ELEMENTS`?

Comment: abuse of language. this is an unexpected behavior, not an undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's good practice that you put the macro in the for loop itself (assuming that you have to use the macro in the first place). You could create a variable which takes the value of the macro and makes it easier to debug your loop.

Comment: @UmNyobe accessing an array element outside the array is actually *undefined behavior*

Comment: you are right, sorry i forget put the right code the out put remain same if we change for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++) to for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++) . i know this is a bizarre question but there should be a logical explanation of everything

Comment: One of the things that you should learn from this is to include a complete program when asking such a question. The fact that we did not know the type of `d` hindered your answerers. In future, for a question like this, supply a complete compilable program. That way we don't need to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand "Conversion rules for comparision between signed and unsigned types". In the example, `for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++)`, here d is signed int, and `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is unsigned, and `d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS` converts d to unsigned. Unsigned -1 is huge number which is not `< TOTAL_ELEMENTS`, so the loop never gets executed. Typecast as shown below. It will work.

```
for(d=-1;d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++)
```

Comment: the d is declared as int d;

Comment: thank you very much,without your help it is very difficult to find out so thanks again. have a nice day

Answer (score 6):

As other stated in their answers, with `d = -1` it does not print anything as in:

```
d <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS
```

`d` is converted to an unsigned integer type (`TOTAL_ELEMENTS` is of type `size_t` because of `sizeof`). After conversion `d` value becomes a huge unsigned integer and the comparison with  `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` value fails.

Then:

`printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);`

will overflow your array as the last element of your array is at index `TOTAL_ELEMENTS - 1` and you access your array up to `TOTAL_ELEMENTS + 1`.

To display your array elements just use the regular form starting from index `0`:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_ELEMENTS; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: you are right, sorry i forget put the right code the out put remain same if we change for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++) to for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++) . i know this is a bizarre question. I know this that putting d=0; will solve this but why putting d -1 doesnt work?

Comment: @user2257769 You didn't the answer to the question: how is `d` declared in your program?

Comment: @user2257769 see answer from @RamPolisetty, your `d` is converted to a unsigned type in the comparison.

Answer (score -1):

try casting TOTAL_ELEMENTS to int

```
for(d=-1;d <= (int)(TOTAL_ELEMENTS);d++)
```

Comment: Lucas is right that the cast is needed for the compile with some compilers, which complain that sizeof returns an unsigned value which can't be converted without loss of range to fit in d (if d is an int).

Comment: Why the downvote? This answer is correct. `d` is converted to an unsigned integer in the comparison and this explains why it fails when `d` is `-1`.

Comment: @NicholasWilson It's `d` that is converted to `size_t` for the comparison.